# Keras/Tensorflow Input to RNN layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to build an RNN in Keras. I don't quite understand the required input format. I can build dense networks no problem, but I think that the RNN layers expect input dimension x batch x time step? Can anyone verify this?

Here is the code I would like to update:

Original code:

```
def get_generative(G_in, dense_dim=200, out_dim=50, lr=1e-3):
   x = Dense(dense_dim)(G_in)
   x = Activation('tanh')(x)
   G_out = Dense(out_dim, activation='tanh')(x)
   G = Model(G_in, G_out)
   opt = SGD(lr=lr)
   G.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
   return G, G_out

G_in = Input(shape=[10])
G, G_out = get_generative(G_in)
G.summary()
```

Modified with GRU layers and some slightly different dimensions:

```
def get_generative(G_in, dense_dim=10, out_dim=37, lr=1e-3):
   clear_session()
   x = GRU(dense_dim, activation='tanh',return_state=True)(G_in)
   G_out = GRU(out_dim, return_state=True)(x)
   G = Model(G_in, G_out)
   opt = SGD(lr=lr)
   G.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
   return G, G_out

G_in = Input(shape=(None,3))
G, G_out = get_generative(G_in)
G.summary()
```

The error that I am seeing with this code is:

> ValueError: Tensor("gru_1/strided_slice:0", shape=(3, 10),
> dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as
> Tensor("strided_slice_1:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32).

If I remove the `None` above, I get:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_1: expected ndim=3,
> found ndim=2

Any explanation would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because you clear the session after creating the input tensor. That is why the input tensor is not coming from the same graph as the rest of your network. To fix this simply leave out the line `clear_session()`.

Another problem with your code: the second GRU layer expects a sequence input, therefore you should use `return_sequences=True` inside the first GRU layer. You probably want to leave out the argument `return_state=True` since that makes the layer return a tuple of tensors (output and state) instead of just one output tensor.

To sum up, the following code should do it:

```
def get_generative(G_in, dense_dim=10, out_dim=37, lr=1e-3):
   x = GRU(dense_dim, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(G_in)
   G_out = GRU(out_dim)(x)
   G = Model(G_in, G_out)
   opt = SGD(lr=lr)
   G.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
   return G, G_out
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried these suggestions already. Here is the Value Error that I get with you code: 
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: It works for me. Are you using `G_in = Input(shape=(None,3))`? It is important that the shape of `G_in` has 2 dimensions (excl batch size)

Comment: Hi Anna, I just posed a follow answer. The code I posted works for me. Thanks for the help. You were right about clear session and I think I have a much better understanding now on the input shape into an RNN layer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that RNN layers expect a 3D tensor input of the form: [num samples, time steps, features].

So we can modify the code above as:

```
def get_generative(G_in, dense_dim=10, out_dim=37, lr=1e-3):
   x = GRU(dense_dim, activation='tanh',return_state=True)(G_in)
   G_out = GRU(out_dim, return_state=True)(x)
   G = Model(G_in, G_out)
   opt = SGD(lr=lr)
   G.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
   return G, G_out

G_in = Input(shape=(1,3))
G, G_out = get_generative(G_in)
G.summary()
```

So what we are saying is that we expect an input of an arbitrary number of samples, each of 1 time step with 3 features.

Anna is correct that clear_session() should not be inside the generator function.

Lastly, if you actually want to input data into the network, its shape should also match what we just discussed. You can do this by using numpy reshape:

`X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))`

Comment: An input with shape `(None, 3)` works just as well as `(1, 3)`. That just means that your input can have variable sequence length, whereas your fixed size forces the input to have sequence length 1. I think my answer provides the correct answer to your question.